# Defining ranges for variables declared in a class (C++)?

Tags: c++, class, variables, range, restriction

Say I have `class galaxy`. A sensible variable to include in this class would be `double mass`. Practically, this is an example of a variable that would have inherent restrictions, especially if considering the galaxies we know of today.

What I want to know is: how would you encode this restriction in the class? I would want an error when trying to create `galaxy Andromeda(unfeasible mass)` for example.

You can obviously do error checks on inputs if you're taking in data, but is there a way to make this inherent in the class?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but may be [user defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) could be of help for your case. So basically you want to specifiy a monitored range of values that can be applied at compile time? You should give us a more concise sample, how you expect the code to look like.

Comment: There's no way to declare a valid range in standard C++. The most common way is to test the input and return/throw an error if it is out of range. I would recommend in this case not to take it in the constructor, but to use encapsulation to create accessors and mutators that do this 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)

Comment: You either need to check the range in the constructor of your class, or create a class called `GalaxyMass` that checks the range in *its* constructor.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes -- I want to be able to define a range of `mass` inside the class such that I'm not able to create an object with a value outside this range at compile time. Thanks for your answer by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify input checking, with a simple wrapper class, to make the check easier

```
template<typename T, T MinRange_, T MaxRange_>
struct RangeRestrictedValue {
    T value;
    RangeRestrictedValue(const char* paramName_ = nullptr) 
    : value(doRangeCheck(T())), paramName(paramName_) {}
    RangeRestrictedValue(const T& value_, const char* paramName_ = nullptr) 
    : value(doRangeCheck(value_)), paramName(paramName_) {}
    RangeRestrictedValue& operator=(const T& value_) {
        value = doRangeCheck(value_); 
        return *this;
    }

    static T& doRangeCheck(const T& value) {
        std::ostringstream message;
        message << (paramName ? paramName : "value") << " is out of range.";
        if(value < MinRange_ || value > MaxRange_) {
            throw std::out_of_range(message.str().c_str());
        }
    }
    const char* paramName;
};
```

And use that like

```
class Galaxy {    
private:
    typedef RangeRestrictedValue<double,MIN_GALAXY_MASS,MAX_GALAXY_MASS> GalaxyMass;
    GalaxyMass mass;
public:
    Galaxy(double mass_) : mass(mass_,"mass") {}
    double mass() const { return mass.value; }
    void mass(double mass_) { mass = mass_; }

    void doSomething() {
       // access mass.value as you need to
    }
};
```

Comment: `doRangeCheck` must return `value`, or else this won't compile. It's a good solution otherwise. Just three suggestions: (1) Make `value` private, add a getter function and a setter which performs the same check as `doRange`. If not, you can break the invariant after construction. (2) Add a `static_assert` to make sure that `MinRange <= MaxRange_`. (3) Restrict `message`'s scope to the `if` block.

Comment: @Christian I've changed my answer considering that.

Comment: String literals cannot be template value parameters, as they have internal linkage.

Comment: @yurikilochek Well, I'll move that back to the constructor again.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I can see what your code does, although I haven't used `template` before. What exactly is it's function here? Thanks a lot for the swift reply!

Comment: @Eurioya I've used a template to make that wrapper feasibe with different data types like `double`, `int`, etc. Also the range is given as template parameters for better readability of the variable definition.